# Prevent my device from switching Wifi

Tags: android, connection, android-wifi

I am developing an app with an ESP8266 in AP mode. Now my problem is, that the Wifi of the Phone disconnect and jump to a other known AP if it recognizes that the ESP has no internet connection.
How can I prevent the android device from switching the AP automatically in my code!
It should stick to the AP after the connection is established.

Thank you very much!